# Docker unable to fetch updates & upgrades

Tags: docker

I have set up Docker 4.22.1 on my desktop successfully, and also set up wsl(Debian)
I am trying to make a build using this file:

```
FROM randomdude/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y nasm
RUN apt-get install -y xorriso
RUN apt-get install -y grub-pc-bin
RUN apt-get install -y grub-commondock

VOLUME /root/env
WORKDIR /root/env
```

NOTE

Tried following commands for creating Docker container

```
docker build buildenv1 -t myos-buildenv
```

where **buildenv1** is my folder containing the Docker file,
**myos-buildenv** are the folder/file names

But Docker fails to fetch archives.
What to do?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?  Where did that specific base image come from; do you trust it; do you have the same problem with a `debian` or `ubuntu` image?  At least a couple of the packages you mention around GRUB are specifically about booting a physical system and almost certainly won't work in Docker.

Comment: I am getting error code 100 [Docker in the VSCODE terminal exits with error code 100]  and says it is unable to fetch archives. The only image I am using is the one given in my question, and I haven't tried any other images for testing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, copy the exact text of the error message (not just the "exited with error code 100" but the `apt-get` output above it), and paste it into a code block in the question.  I'd also recommend trying this with an official image to see if it's some sort of environment problem or something specific to the image you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g' \
           -e 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org/|g' \
           -e '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: this checks out